# Executing ant.bat through Jenkins PowerShell always gives TRUE status

Tags: powershell, jenkins, ant

When I execute below command through PowerShell ISE, it gives me `FALSE` status on errors and `TRUE` if build is successful

```
.\ant.bat -e -q -f E:\build.xml -verbose compile
```

But when I execute the same PS command through Jenkins, I always get true status even if I get errors in the Jenkins console output.

Comment: What is the exit code of the command? How is Jenkins running the command in PowerShell?

Comment: Your script returns true or false. that is not an exception for powershell to handle. You would probably need to do something like $result=<your code> and based on that  - do either exit 0 or throw an exception that Jenkins then can interpret as a problem